# matplotlib twinx xticks at specific locations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the code below, in the x-axis, i want to show only the parameter values for which i have the metric values which are 5,10,20 and 50.
I want the parameter values to span the x-axis.

How I can do it ?.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np;
from matplotlib import rc;

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots();
rc('mathtext', default='regular');
x = np.array([5,10,20,50]);
cg1 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8]);
cg2 = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.4,0.7]);
cg3 = np.array([0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6]);
lns1 = ax1.plot(x,cg1,'b*:',label='1 CG');
lns2 = ax1.plot(x,cg2,'bo--',label='2 CG');
lns3 = ax1.plot(x,cg3,'bs-',label='3 CG');
ax1.set_ylabel('CG',color='b');
ax1.set_ylim([0,1]);
ax1.set_xlim([4,55]);
ax1.set_xticklabels([5,10,20,50]);
ax1.set_xlabel('K');

ax2 = ax1.twinx();
ld1 = np.array([0.8,0.5,0.2,0.2]);
ld2 = np.array([0.6,0.2,0.3,0.2]);
ld3 = np.array([0.2,0.4,0.6,0.2]);
lns4 = ax2.plot(x,ld1,'k*:',label='1 ld');
lns5 = ax2.plot(x,ld2,'ko--',label='2 ld');
lns6 = ax2.plot(x,ld3,'ks-',label='3 ld');

lns = lns1 + lns2 + lns3 + lns4 + lns5 + lns6;
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns];
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc='best', ncol=2);
ax2.set_ylabel('LD',color='k');
ax2.set_ylim([0,1]);
ax2.set_xlim([4,55]);
plt.show();
```

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you mean by `I want the parameter values to span the x-axis.`?

Comment: I want the x-axis to show only 5,10,20 and 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing line with `ax1.set_xlim([4,55])` with this line:

```
ax1.set_xticks(x)
```

You may also want to remove `ax2.set_xlim(...)`.

Does it give you what you expected?

**UPDATE Following comments**:

Please use these lines (NOTE: the order matters!):

```
ax1.set_xlim([4,55]);
ax1.set_xticks(x)
...
ax2.set_xlim([4,55]);
ax2.set_xticks(x)
```

And remove anything else that touches xticks, like any of these:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels([5,10,20,50]);
ax2.set_xticklabels([5,10,20,50]);
```

This should produce a chart like this:

[image]

Which has limits at `[4, 55]` and only selected tick values visible.

Comment: without set_xlim first and last points (for 5 and 50) end up on the y-axis.

Comment: i set xlim because i want some space between y axes and the data points.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry - missed the point there. I will add this to me answer.